# Reading through a file list and checking directory for file's existence using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was hoping someone might have a good idea for this. I haven't seen it quite answered on here, although I have seen bits of pieces of what I think I need.

I'd like a Python script to read through a text file, and check if each filename listed in that text file exists. I'd then like it to write TRUE and FALSE values out to a text/csv.

The source text file (called dirlist) looks like:

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
```

My Python is limited to scouring the internet and piecing things together. I'm trying to learn!

What I'm thinking:

```
with open("dirlist") as f:
    for line in f:
        if os.path.exists():
            open("status", 'w')
            write TRUE
        else:
            open("status", 'w')
            write FALSE
```

I know this is not Pythonic and probably ugly! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically the right idea, but you can simplify your code a bit:

```
with open('dirlist', 'r') as f, open('status', 'w') as status:
    for line in f.readlines():
        exists = os.path.exists(line)
        status.write(str(exists).upper())
```

Note that this way, we make sure not to have leaking file handles for `'status'` (by including it in the `with` statement). We also don't need to use an `if` statement - we can just stringify the boolean return value of `os.path.exists()`. Using `f.readlines()` here ensures that we don't get newline characters (`\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` depending on your OS) at the end of each line.

Comment: Thanks! How exactly would I write the string boolean returns to new lines? Right now, it returns "TRUETRUE" all in one line.

Comment: After the `status.write()` line, just add `status.write('\n')`. Or, change the `status.write()` line to `status.write(str(exists).upper() + '\n')`.

Comment: Shoot, well now I have a whitespace problem. The batch process which spits out my dirlist.txt file is likely the culprit. I believe that the returns for each new line are being read as whitespace by Python and therefore returning FALSE when the files in fact exist.

Comment: can I use a wildcard here?

Comment: @user3298895 What you should do is process `line` in the `for` loop to make sure that there are no garbage characters. It may be useful to use `line = line.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: well alright! line.strip() worked wonders. learned a lot today. thanks folks

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile = open("out.csv","w")
with open("dirlist") as f:
     result = list(map(os.path.exists,f))
     outfile.write(str(result).upper()[1:-1])
outfile.close()
```

you might need to do

```
result = list(map(lambda fname:os.path.exists(fname.strip()),f))
```